# create jar file with images and database

Tags: java, netbeans, image, jar

Hi I am using NetBeans IDE and I have my images (what I am using in my project) in a folder named Images. When I am building jar it doesn't take that images. The code I am using to set image is, 
          `buttonObj.setIcon(new ImageIcon("\Images\a.jpg")` any help please.

Comment: How do you build your jar-file?

Comment: @Peter Using NetBeans -> clean and build option.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with

```
URL loadingUrl = this.getClass().getResource("/images/a.jpg");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(loadingUrl);
```

using the `getClass().getResource(..)` should be the correct approach to load files from a JAR. But remembers to check documentation for precise specification (if I'm not wrong it prepends the fully qualified package to the path you are loading from)